# Getting stuck with creating better index (Optimize Join)

Tags: mysql, performance, join, optimization, query-performance

Im using the below query and it took min `5s to max 11s`. I tried to create single column and multi-column index. But still I can't able to increase it's performance.

### Row count on each table:

- tbl1 - 400000
- tbl2 - 200000
- tbl3 - 50

### Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `modified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `customer` varchar(155) DEFAULT NULL,
  `social` enum( 'Facebook','twitter') DEFAULT 'LI',
  `grade` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Monthly` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Off_comments` text,
  `createDate` datetime DEFAULT NULL
  );

create table tbl2 
(
id int  NOT NULL 
);

create table tbl3 (
id int, frnd_id int
);
```

### Select Query:

```
SELECT    `T1`.*, 
          `T2`.`Card_No` 
FROM      `tbl1` `T1` 
LEFT JOIN `tbl2` `T2` 
ON        T1.id = T2.id 
LEFT JOIN `tbl3` 
ON        T3.id = T2.On_site_id
WHERE     T1.modified<=Subtime(Now(),'00:00:10') 
AND       T1.customer != 'bhuvi'
AND       T1.social !='Facebook' 
AND       T1.social != 'twitter' 
AND       T3.frnd_id= '4' 
AND       T1.grade IN ('A','B', 'O') 
AND       ( 
                    T1.Monthly IS NULL 
          OR        T1.Monthly = 1) 
AND       ( 
                    Off_comments IS NULL 
          OR        Off_comments = '' 
          OR        Off_comments="''") 
ORDER BY  `T1.createDate`;
```

### Indexed columns:

- tbl1 - id,modified,customer, social,frnd_id
- tbl2 - id
- tbl3 - id

### Explain plan:

```
Filesort
+- TEMPORARY
   table          temporary(tbl3,T2,T1)
   +- JOIN
      +- Filter with WHERE
      |  +- Bookmark lookup
      |     +- Table
      |     |  table          T1
      |     |  possible_keys  fk_T_1_idx
      |     +- Index lookup
      |        key            T1->fk_T_1_idx
      |        possible_keys  fk_T_1_idx
      |        key_len        5
      |        ref            db.T2.id
      |        rows           1
      +- JOIN
         +- Index lookup
         |  key            T2->id
         |  possible_keys  PRIMARY, id
         |  key_len        5
         |  ref            db.t3.id
         |  rows           2537
         +- Index lookup
            key            tbl3->INX_frnd_id
            possible_keys  PRIMARY,INX_frnd_id
            key_len        5
            ref            const
            rows           16
```

Comment: Could you please post the entire table definition as well as the current execution plan?  Also, is this a truly representative query or do the number of arguments in the where clause change?

Comment: This is the exact query. I'll post my table definition.

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: Probably irrelevant to the performance issue but `T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON  T1.id = T2.id`? And both `id` being `auto_increment`? What is going on there?

Comment: Oh, wrong table,I have updated now, `T1 id is the FK of T2`

Comment: OK. But you should really put the whole table definitions in the question. Including all columns and foreign keys.

Comment: Do you have an index on `T3 (frnd_id, id)`? Try adding one and also rewrite the query to join T3 with: `JOIN tbl3 T3
ON   T3.id =` **`T1.id`**

Comment: Sorry, I can't post the complete definition. Added the index `T3 (frnd_id, id)`, but still its taking 5s. :(

Comment: You can at least post definitions that work. The ones you have will produce errors if someone tries to run an example. You can use https://dbfiddle.uk or http://www.sqlfiddle.com or http://rextester.com

Comment: Did you try the query by editing the `LEFT JOIN tbl3 T3 ON T3.id = T2.id` to `INNER JOIN tbl3 T3 ON T3.id = T1.id`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72054/discussion-between-ypercube-and-sqladmin).

Answer (score 1):

First, let's clean up the data.

Is `Monthly` a true/false value?  Then use 0/1 and put it in `TINYINT NOT NULL`.  Or is it tri-state:  Yes/No/unspecified?

If `Off_comments` is an optional string, then cleanse the data so that the empty string and `''` are turned into `NULL` when it is stored.  (Meanwhile, one or two `UPDATEs` can clean up the data.)

I recommend those because `OR` is hard to optimize, and this will probably eliminate such.

`LEFT` says that the 'right' table is optional.  Yet `AND t3...` says that you must find a row.  So change both `LEFT JOINs` to `JOINs`.

Once that is done, it *may* be efficient to check for `T3.frnd_id= '4'` *first* instead of *last*.  Could it be that there aren't many rows with `4`?

Indexes...

Assuming the above works, T3 needs `INDEX(frnd_id, id)`, then T2 needs `INDEX(On_site_id, id)`.

If the optimizer prefers to start with T1, first look for any `=` things in the `WHERE`.  But, the only possibility is `monthly`, depending on the discussion above.  `Off_comments` is not a candidate for indexing since it is `TEXT`.

I'll digress a moment.  What is `T3` about?  It has only 50 rows?  Perhaps it is "over-normalization"?  If so, couldn't you simply put `frnd_id` into `T2`?

Grrr... Have you "simplified" the question?  This seems invalid:  `social enum( 'Facebook','twitter') DEFAULT 'LI',` since `LI` is not an option in the enum!

Grrr-squared...  This is probably not what you wanted:

```
`T1.createDate`
```

Instead:

```
`T1`.`createDate`
```

*Please* fix those and *any other* mis-simplifications!

T1 may be able to use `INDEX(createDate)`.

One more thing:  1:1 relationships (`T1.id = T2.id`) are usually a questionable design.  Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY` on both tables?